# Deploy An Application on Azure, Need Some Pointers

Tags: .net, azure

I'm new at azure and it environment, so if its not suitable question my sincere apology...

I'll try to simplified as i can:

I programmed two project in .NET:

1. Engine -  This project does all the work.("Business layer")
2. Presentation - This project is only the GUI for the engine.("Presentation Layer")

Both of the project communicate with each other.

The engine have API (DCOM), so it can be access from any where in the Local Area Newwork.

**Now** i want to upload only the engine on the azure and access it from my computer.

How can i upload my application ? Any useful tips or articles/tutorials ?

I saw a lot of Microsoft article but i didnt pick up much from there...

Thanks.

**Update:**

I created a Virtual Machine and installed my Engine there, everything is working good till now.

Now I search a way for my website (asp.net MVC 4) that I publish on Azure to communicate with the software that installed on the virtual machine i created( send a file to the software and get it back).

Any idea how can i accomplish that ? how can the website connect and invoke a procedure in the VM ? and transfers files to there and back/

Thanks Again.

Comment: Is the Engine a Windows service and the GUI a fat client (Windows Forms/WPF)?

Comment: **Update:**

I created a Virtual Machine and installed my Engine there, everything is working good till now.

Now I search a way for my website (asp.net MVC 4) that I publish on Azure to communicate with the software that installed on the virtual machine i created( send a file to the software and get it back).

Any idea how can i accomplish that ? how can the website connect and invoke a procedure in the VM ? and transfers files to there and back/

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the engine is implemented as a .NET COM+ Serviced Component (since there are references to both .NET and DCOM server)

If the 'engine' is already hosted in Azure IaaS VM, you would need to open a VM endpoint (and, if necessary, set an ACL to control who is allowed to access that VM ) to make it accessible to the engine: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

BTW, apart from deploying the 'engine' in IaaS VM, you can consider hosting in either a web or worker role in Azure PaaS Compute: see this link for more details: http://michaelwasham.com/2011/05/15/deploying-a-com-servicedcomponent-to-windows-azure/

Comment: Simon i decided to host my site on the VM along with my application, to get good integration between the web application and engine.
there something wrong with that ? what you think ?

Comment: Ron, sorry, I was OOF - as a stop-gap measure this should work but you might consider architecting your app to scale and take advantage of cloud infrastructure benefits - decouple tiers to scale independently, move them into cloud constructs - PaaS roles, etc.